# Set a default category - if the user didn't select one- before creating a post

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, admin, hooks

Is there some option `hook` to set a default `category` for a `custom_post_type` when the user didn't choose any ?

For example in `RoR` it's very simple - by using `before_save` filter you can set whatever you want before `update` model, or `before_create` - before creating it ...

How can I `hook` some `action` after the user clicks `Publish` but before the `action` ends .. and check if some `category` was choosen for a `custom_post_type` - if not, set some default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

> Source is from @[Michael Fields](http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/)

```
/**
 * Set default cat for cpt
 * @source {https://circlecube.com/says/2013/01/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomy-default/}
 * @source {http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/}
 * @license   GPLv2
 */
function set_default_object_terms_203962( $post_id, $post ) {
if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
    $defaults = array(
        //'your_taxonomy_id' => array( 'your_term_slug', 'your_term_slug' )
        'post_tag' => array( 'taco', 'banana' ),
        'monkey-faces' => array( 'see-no-evil' ),
        );
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type );
    foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
        if ( empty( $terms ) && array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $defaults ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $defaults[$taxonomy], $taxonomy );
        }
    }}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_default_object_terms_203962', 100, 2 );
```

This works like a charm for us.

*ps, there is also a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/post-type-requirements-checklist) which could be helpfull to 'force' some of your wishes before an user(read editor/author etc.) even can publish.*